# Is there a way to see GPU System Memory broken down process-by-process?

Tags: windows-7, gpu, aero, process-explorer, memory-leaks

I am trying to figure out which app in my system is responsible for the memory spikes (note that the spikes are seen on GPU tab).

[image: xxx]

[image: yyy]

[Here's a question](https://superuser.com/q/68054/23583) that spawned this one.

*EDIT* To show System Information graphs in Process Explorer, try clicking on any of the graphs at the top of main ProcessExplorer window.

Comment: I would approach the problem by ignoring it. Memory use is normal -- that's what memory is for.

Comment: I saw the linked question. I don't get the link. Are *you* experiencing poor performance? If so, why not ask about troubleshooting it?

Comment: You really haven't, I'm afraid. For example, without knowing whether the memory spikes correlate with the error messages, or whether the memory spikes correlate with poor performance (or, for that matter, whether you're problem is poor performance or just the cosmetic problem of an annoying error message), you're not likely to get useful help with your problem. You've hidden from us all the information about what the problem actually is.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz The possibility of poor performance has been cleverly circumvented by Microsoft engineers.  They simply disable Aero, freeing all the memory resources that were snapped up by it.  End-points of the spikes correlate to auto-disabling of Aero.  I was stubborn and re-enabled it again and again, causing multiple such spikes.

Comment: How did u launch that window. Is it a native monitoring tool in Windows? I just asking because I'm not sure how to launch it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible to see the break-down by process by adding a GPU System Bytes column to Process Explorer main process list.

*EDIT* Note the added GPU System Bytes tab in the image below.

[image: yyy]

[image: xxx]

Comment: Which tab?​​​​​

Comment: @Synetech I've added some screen captures to assist with the task of adding a column.

Answer (score 0):

I would hazard a guess that the OP is running dual video card in a non SLI/Crossfire setup and that those spikes are your GPU accelerated applications (Chrome,Firefox, IE9-IE10) doing something.

If the above is true and you're getting Aero "should be disabled" or "Aero has been disabled" then your options are either use CrossFire, don't surf/run videos (or whatever gpu accelerated applications you are using) on those monitors, or disable gpu acceleration.

Otherwise, just ignore it as somebody stated.

(I would comment but I apparently don't have enough rep/posts to do so).